# How to store the values in hashmap in javascript

Tags: javascript, hashmap

I am parsing xml file in javascript and i am extracting all its values

```
function loadXMLDoc() {
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
  myFunction(this);
}
};
xmlhttp.open("GET", "/ccm/rpt/repository /workitem?fields=workitem/projectArea/*", true);
xmlhttp.send();
}

function myFunction(xml) {
var x,y,j, i, xmlDoc, txt,txt1;
xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
txt = "";
txt1="";
x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("contextId");
for (i = 0; i< x.length; i++) {
txt += x[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue;

}
y = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("name");
for (j = 0; i< y.length; j++) {
txt1 += y[j].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
}
}
```

and now my target is to store the value of name as key and contextId as value (HashMap concept) , So is it possible to achieve the same,Also please let me if my question sounds ambiguous
Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add properties to objects as if they were hashmaps, have a look at this example:

```
var myObj = {prop1: 12};
var propName = "prop2";

myObj[propName] = 10;

console.log(myObj);
```

Which outputs:

```
{prop1: 12, prop2: 10}
```

In your example, lets assume x and y are of equal length, then we can add to the object in a single loop:

```
var x,y,j, i, xmlDoc, myHashMap;

xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
myHashMap = {};

x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("contextId");
y = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("name");

for (i = 0; i< x.length; i++) {
  var value = x[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
  var key = y[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
  myHashMap[key] = value;
}

console.log(myHashMap);
```

Comment: But again if you see my code the value of x and y is getting dynamically increasing but ur code is static, can u give example with reference to my code if possible?

Comment: Thanks for quick update,just one more thing like if i want to see the output in console,what shall i do console.log()?

Comment: Like what value is added as key and what as a value

Comment: Yea, you can add console.log(myHashMap); after the loop to see the result. Alternatively console.log(value); and console.log(key); inside the loop.